# need to add the .down-arrow class to the div when the accordion opens up

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I created arrow images using css.
- but the problem is i need to add the .down-arrow class to the div when the accordion opens up.
- right now I added one image but not sure how to add the other image.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it
- providing my code below

```or-tag-here
.down-arrow {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-55deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `invisible` class like this

```
.invisible{
display:none;
}
```

And then

```
var upArrowClassName = 'up-arrow' + (this.props._selected ? '' : ' invisible');
var downArrowClassName = 'down-arrow' + (this.props._selected ? ' invisible' : '');
```

And then apply these classes to the divs

```
<div className={upArrowClassName}></div>
<div className={downArrowClassName}></div>
```

At any given point in time according to the value of `this.props._selected` one will have the `invisible` class attached to it and won't be visible.

Comment: can you update the code in fiddle its so confusing :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/30/

Remember to create the `invisible` class in CSS though.

Comment: hey i created the class but still its not working fine...can you help me http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/32/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/36/ - You should have put the details in the `.down-arrow` class

Comment: @mirnalmech: hey can you tell me the reason...it will help me so much

Comment: The `.invisible` class hides the div when it is true. So when `this.props._selected` is true the `.down-arrow` gets the `.invisible` class and is hidden and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

When an accordion is opened, a new "selected" class is added to the accordion section. Rather than trying to change the class itself, just use this new 'selected' class and change the rotate property on your existing arrow. eg:

```
.selected .up-arrow {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: so your speaking with respect to this class----->         var className = 'accordion-section' + (this.props._selected ? ' selected' : '');

Comment: Yes that'r correct. So when an accordion is closed, the class on that div is "accordion-section", when it is opened it is "accordion-section selected". The arrow is a child element to that div, so you can use that "selected" class to change it's style accordingly. As such you dont need to make any other changes to your markup, just add some new css. You could have, eg:
.accordion-section .up-arrow {border-color:red}
.accordion-section.selected up-arrow {border-color:pink}

Comment: I added first three sections in one div and another three sections in another div....so if I click section 3 and then click section 4 section 3 does not close....where as if I click section section 3 and then clcik section 2 it will close section...can you tell me how to fix it....I need to maintain three sections in a div so that I can include heading for each collection of sections...example here http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/41/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same `this.props._selected` in your Accordion section component as:

```
var className1 = this.props._selected ? 'down-arrow' : 'up-arrow';
```

And change the `className` in render as:

```
className={className1}
```

Also make some changes in `.down-arrow` class as:

```
.down-arrow {
  border-top: .15em solid #0b6997;
  border-right: .15em solid #0b6997;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9f5egd69/).